# Using `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.name.com")` without having to provide the username and password

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I've built an application that will be deployed with ClickOnce that, upon startup, will need to check the currently logged in user's Identity/Name, and compare it to the Active Directory Groups on our domain in order to set up appropriate permissions in the application.

I can do this by "hard coding" a username and password into the application, and passing these credentials into the `PrincipalContext` constructor, i.e.,

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.name.com", username, password);
```

The problem is that I don't want to have to store the username and password in the application (and I don't want to have to prompt the user for their username and password, either).

I've seen many examples online using the constructor without specifying credentials, but this doesn't work on our domain.

**Is there a setting/permission in the Domain or "Domain Users" Group properties that I can configure to get this to work?**

My current code is as follows (note that :

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of all Active Directory Groups the specified username is a member of.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userName">The username of the user in DOMAIN\Username format</param>
/// <param name="domain">The name of the domain server, e.g., server.domain.com (not DOMAIN or DOMAIN.COM or SERVER)</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> GetUserGroups(string userName, string domain)
{
    if (userName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return null;

    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
    var userPc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);

    if (userPc == null) return null;

    var src = userPc.GetGroups(pc);
    var result = new List<string>();
    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
    return result;
}
```

And I'm essentially calling is like this:

```
var userGroups = GetUserGroups(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name, "server.domain.com");
```

Comment: "... this doesn't work on our domain." Can you explain that? Are you saying that you can't query the LDAP / ADS server without username and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"You've seen many examples online using the constructor without specifying credentials"* This should work on your machine as far as your computer belongs to the domain and the user is logged in.

For me the error can come from the fact that when you use :

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
```

`domain` is supposed to be the domain name, given by the environnement variable `USERDNSDOMAIN` if the user is logged into the domain, and not *"The name of the domain server, e.g., server.domain.com"* as you write into the comment.

Comment: Oddly enough, this morning when I came in to the office and ran the code (without changing it) it just worked. A chaos monkey must have been rustling around in our network yesterday. Curiously, our domain is actually `server.sci.com`, which works, as does the `USERDNSDOMAIN` value of just `sci.com`.

Comment: And 5 hours later this solution errors out with "A local error occurred". I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: You don't give any clue, first can you log the exception. Second without clues, statisticaly your problem comes from your DNS resolution (80% of the AD authentication problem comes from that)

Comment: @JPBlanc is there anyway i can prove it? it is issue with DNS resolution? What i can tell them to check?